# How to pass variables across different contexts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql

The code is like:

```
http_adapter = ::GraphQL::Client::HTTP.new(schema_url) do
  def headers(context)
    {
      'Authorization': "Bearer #{}",
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  end
end
```

What I need is to pass a variable from `http_adapter` level context to the inner `Bearer #{}`. Also I cannot pass a constant or an environment varible since the token expires every several hours. So how can I pass in the token properly? Thanks.

The code above is part of an instance method by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One might use [`Module#define_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-define_method) to preserve a scope:

```
http_adapter = ::GraphQL::Client::HTTP.new(schema_url) do
  define_method :headers do |context|
    {
      'Authorization': "Bearer #{}", # outer context is available here
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  end
end
```

---

Or, one might use a dedicated instance variable in `::GraphQL::Client::HTTP`:

```
::GraphQL::Client::HTTP.instance_variable_set(:@bearer, ...)
http_adapter = ::GraphQL::Client::HTTP.new(schema_url) do
  def headers(context)
    {
      'Authorization': "Bearer #{self.class.instance_variable_get(:@bearer)}",
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  end
end
```

---

Or, alternatively, one might perform [the initialization](https://github.com/github/graphql-client/blob/master/lib/graphql/client/http.rb#L33) themselves:

```
http_adapter = ::GraphQL::Client::HTTP.new(schema_url)
http_adapter.class.send(:attr_writer, :bearer)
http_adapter.bearer = ...
http_adapter.extend(Module.new do
  def headers(context)
    {
      'Authorization': "Bearer #{@bearer}",
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  end
end)
```

Comment: Many thanks @mudasobwa And I tested all 3 ways you pointed out. The second way works perfectly. The first one still cannot get the outer context, and the third one throws an error on line 3: NoMethodError: undefined method `bearer=' for #<Class:#<GraphQL::Client::HTTP:0x007faa2d912e48>>

Comment: I have fixed the third one, the first one works for me.